# How can hide response Header on bad Request 400 in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

[image]
My requirement is how can hide response Header on bad Request 400 in Asp.net i was trying solve the problems.i will try add some code in web.config file as well as global.asax file but it is not working here i am attach a image for better understanding.can u figure out this problmes.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="Remove RESPONSE_Server" >
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Server" pattern=".+" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="Company name" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
{
    Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
    Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
}
```

Comment: Try : 
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
  </security>
</system.webServer>

Comment: not working server header is visible.

Comment: add that and then remove header ?

Comment: already add not working on bad request.any other solution.